# Multitasking Android 5.0

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, multitasking

I have an LG-V400 running Android Lollipop 5.0.2. I want to be able to multitask in dual windows with apps that did not come with this device. When I try to multitask, I am given this prompt:

[image: prompt]

which only allows me to multitask with Google apps. How can I multitask with two completely different apps? (i.e. SoundCloud and DropBox)

(I am fine with rooting my device if that is what the solution requires, although I would prefer not to.)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is an xposed module called [xmultiwindow](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.lovewuchin.xposed.xmultiwindow) that will do the trick.  You need to root your phone and install the xposed framework.  I can't confirm if its compatible with your model though but try it out.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I have already tried to install the Xposed framework (for a different purpose) but couldn't install the TWRP manager. I ended up accidentally factory resetting my device and nearly bricked it. Any other solutions would be helpful, but thank you for your answer.